# How to identify processors with Accessed and Dirty Flags for EPT

Tags: virtual-machine, intel, ept

I want to find a Intel processor that support EPT accessed/dirty bits, but I can't find it till now. The Intel developer's manual just said that some processors support that, but it didn't make this clear.

I know that I can use rdmsr to determine if the EPT table supports access and dirty bits. However I would like to know how to identify a processor before I've purchased it that has this support.

Answer (score 0):

Intel provides that information at http://ark.intel.com/products/virtualizationtechnology.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I found that the 4th generation Intel processors support accessed and dirty bits for EPT ( e.g. i3-4130 ).